# HTML/CSS element position

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how can I position this ring in exact same position? I mean when I resize window it does not stay in the same place. I understand that i should not use top or left like I did here but I just don't know what to use here.

```css
.container{
  border-style: solid;
}

.gps_ring {

 border: 3px solid #363347;
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 32px;
 border-radius: 32px;
 
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 
 -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 
 animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 
 opacity: 0.0;
 top: 30%;
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
}
 
/* webkit - safari, chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
50% {opacity: 1.0;}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
}
/* no vendor prefix - firefox */
@keyframes pulsate {
0% { transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0; }
50% { opacity: 1.0; }
100% { transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Australia-Map-Transparent-PNG.png">
  <div class="gps_ring"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pfvgvyqj/

Comment: i know you've just marked a right answer, but if you want a resposive solution (width AND height), take a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a responsive solution using javascrpt.
Your GPS-Ring still be on the same location on each mapsizes. If you want to use a smaller map then 100%, just set maps "width: 100%" to any width you want. the height will be calculated automatically.

resizing is also supported using the eventlistener.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize',function(event){
  setGpsPosition();
});

function setGpsPosition(){
  var map = document.getElementById('map');
  var gps_ring = document.getElementById('gps_ring');

  map.style.height = map.offsetWidth / 1.4 + 'px';
  gps_ring.style.marginTop = map.offsetHeight * 0.3 + 'px';
  gps_ring.style.marginLeft = map.offsetWidth * 0.5 + 'px';
}
setGpsPosition();
```

```css
.container{
  border-style: solid;
}
#map {
  background: url('http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Australia-Map-Transparent-PNG.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#gps_ring {
 border: 3px solid #363347;
 -webkit-border-radius: 32px;
 border-radius: 32px;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
 opacity: 0.0;
  position: absolute; 
}
 
/* webkit - safari, chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
50% {opacity: 1.0;}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
}
/* no vendor prefix - firefox */
@keyframes pulsate {
0% { transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0; }
50% { opacity: 1.0; }
100% { transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="map">
    <div id="gps_ring"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> if you want to edit the position of your GPS-Ring note this:
>
> `map.offsetHeight * 0.3 + 'px'` - the 0.3 is equal to 30% (from the top)
>
> `map.offsetWidth * 0.5 + 'px';` - the 0.5 is equal to 50% (from the left)

Here's a fiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/fv2ocLyL/

Answer (score 2):

If you add position relative to your container, the absolute positioning references the height and size of the container.

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3f9d629m/2/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container{
  border-style: solid;
}

.gps_ring {

 border: 3px solid #363347;
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 32px;
 border-radius: 32px;
 
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 
 -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 
 animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 
 opacity: 0.0;
 top: 5em;
 left: 19rem;
 position: absolute;
}
 
/* webkit - safari, chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
50% {opacity: 1.0;}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
}
/* no vendor prefix - firefox */
@keyframes pulsate {
0% { transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0; }
50% { opacity: 1.0; }
100% { transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Australia-Map-Transparent-PNG.png">
  <div class="gps_ring"></div>
</div>
```